# How to use "sales_quote_collect_totals_before" Observer in magento2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, event-observer

I want to use event  **sales_quote_collect_totals_before** observer in Magento2.

Comment: Hi, Please don't edit your question direct. If you get any error when apply any solution so please comment it.

Comment: Run this command
php bin/magento setup:upgrad
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: @VithalBariya same error after running commands

Comment: Clear your var/di folder and again run the same command

Comment: I want to use event sales_quote_collect_totals_before observer in Magento2. what are you using it for?
what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

**you can add `etc/events.xml`:**

```
<event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
<observer name="event_name" instance="Package\Module\Observer\Observer" />
</event>
```

**And You have to Add Ovserver.php**:-

```
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();               
   }
```

Comment: getting error check question again.

Comment: Run php bin/magento c:f,  php bin/magneto setup:di:compile

Comment: same error after running commands

Comment: It should be events.xml, not event.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create `events.xml` at below path of custom module.

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
    <observer name="your_event_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ObserverName" />
</event>
```

> Vendor/Module/Observer/ObserverName.php

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


 class ObserverName implements ObserverInterface
 {

protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,

) {

    $this->_request = $request;
    .....
}

/**
 * Manages redirect
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
   $quote = $observer->getQuote(); 
    echo $quote->getGrandTotal(); exit;
    // Prints your Grand Total

}
}
```

Comment: getting error check question again.

Comment: @ChandraKumar, You can use quote object to get order details, Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create **events.xml** file to catch event.

> app/code/Module Name Space/Module Name/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
        <observer name="change_sales_quote_collect_totals_before" instance="Module Name Space\Module Name\Observer\Totalsbefore" />
    </event>
 </config>
```

Create **Observer** file to catch event.

> app/code/Module Name Space/Module Name/Observer/Totalsbefore.php

```
<?php
namespace Module Name Space\Module Name\Observer;

class Totalsbefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //Put your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error check question again.

Answer (score 0):

> etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
        <observer name="custom_sales_quote_collect_totals_before" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Observer/SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        //you can do your custom code here..

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error check question again.